# Relationship type cannot be found under the list of attribute types

Tags: flutter, relationship, appwrite

I cannot find the attribute type of relationship. I am relatively new to appwrite so I am sure if I am doing something wrong or if the type no longer exists

I read the documentation which has relationship as part of the attribute types, and a couple of youtube tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe be on an older version of Appwrite? Relationships were added in Appwrite 1.3.0.

You may have also been on Appwrite Cloud, which may have been on an older version of Appwrite at the time. Appwrite Cloud is not on 1.4, so relationships should be available now.